# Active magnetic protection against cosmic radiation - Can anyone provide articles or summarize the latest developments?

Tags: magnetic-field, reference-request, shielding, cosmic-radiation

A European project purports to have a practical magnetic shield for cosmic rays, based on four MgB<sub>2</sub> toroidL coils<sup>1</sup> oriented around the spacecraft like the lines of longitude around the globe. I can't find a source for the figures cited in the report.
The final report on Space Radiation Superconductive Shielding, dated 2015 is available here:
https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/313224/reporting

This 2013 report is behind a paywall:
https://www.scribd.com/document/369859609/active-magnetic-shielding-for-long-duration-manned-space-missions

---

<sup>1</sup>[Magnesium diboride superconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_diboride#Superconductors) (Tc = 39 K, Jc = 10<sup>9</sup> A/m<sup>2</sup> at 5 Tesla) is a relatively low cost and promising [Type II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-II_superconductor) superconductor being explored for large electromagnet applications.

Comment: Great question!